# Simplest way to group items to array list

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get a response from another API to then group the matching values to send to another API into a single array when matching. I figure one way would be to rebuild the entire object by doing a foreach on each item but I am looking for a simpler way (possibly through Linq?) to be able to group this data.

Displaying example in JSON for ease of reading, ultimately would instead be c# objects

Input:

```
[{
    "itemID": 123,
    "orderedItemID": 1,
    "queuePosition": 1
},
{
    "itemID": 123,
    "orderedItemID": 2,
    "queuePosition": 3
},
{
    "itemID": 123,
    "orderedItemID": 3,
    "queuePosition": 5
},
{
    "itemID": 456,
    "orderedItemID": 10,
    "queuePosition": 1
},
{
    "itemID": 456,
    "orderedItemID": 14,
    "queuePosition": 2
}]
```

Desired Output

```
[{
    "itemID": 123,
    "queuePosition": [1,3,5]
},
{
    "itemID": 456,
    "queuePosition": [1,2]
}]
```

A bit more info as well for output class:

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class QueuePosition
{
[DataMember(Name = "itemID")]
public int ItemID { get; set;}

[DataMember(Name = "queuePosition")]
public IEnumerable<int> QueuePosition { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Are you deserializing the JSON from the first API to get it into a .NET Object?

Comment: Yeah, JSON is just for making it easier to read for desired goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `GroupBy`; if you have a *collection* of objects, say an array:

```
var source = new MyObject[] {
  new MyObject(itemID : 123, orderedItemID :  1, queuePosition : 1),
  ...
  new MyObject(itemID : 456, orderedItemID : 14, queuePosition : 2), 
};
```

The code can be

```
QueuePosition[] result = source
  .GroupBy(item => item.itemID)
  .Select(group => new QueuePosition() {
     ItemID = group.Key,
     QueuePosition = group
       .Select(item => item.queuePosition)
       .ToArray() 
   })
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the exact answer i needed. Thanks a bunch, I've spent way too much time on this part of the code lol.

Answer (score 1):

The grouping can be done using Linq as follows, supposed some actual types are used.

```
var Result =
    Input.GroupBy( iItem => iItem.itemID )
         .Select( iGroup => new GroupType
                            {
                                itemID = iGroup.Key,
                                queuePosition
                                   = iGroup.Select( iItem => iItem.queuePosition )
                                           .ToArray()
                            }
                );
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, fantastic username.

Comment: @roninmbattousai Thanks, it took me several days to make it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LINQ you have to first convert the JSON to a C# object.
To do this you can use JsonConvert from Newtonsoft [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

After this you should take a look at GroupBy from linq [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

Comment: He probably knows that already. "Displaying example in JSON for ease of reading, ultimately would instead be c# objects"

Comment: Yeah GroupBy was what i think i was hoping for figuring out. Json stuff is just easier for visibility from my perspective (being a person who has spent more time on front end and back end sql, just now getting to be the middle layer). Thanks!